# Quiera saber que es, ¿Qué es HTML?

Tags: html, html5

> Yo encontré que es un lenguaje de marcado y otros dicen que no es un lenguaje.

Comment: HTML Es un lenguaje de marcado de hipertexto, sin embargo **no es un lenguaje de programación**

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas no aportan nada a SOES, la respuesta a esto se encuentra fácilmente en Wikipedia ya en español. Acá te dejo el [enlace](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> HTML, por sus siglas en inglés es HyperText Markup Language, por lo tanto si es un lenguaje de marcado de hipertexto, claro esta que no es un lenguaje de programación, si no un lenguaje de marcado.

https://www.slideshare.net/AprendeEnsenando/11-qu-es-html-parte-2-de-5

Answer (score 1):

HTML por sus siglas *Hyper Text Markup Languaje* o *Lenguaje de marcado de hipertexto* es un lenguaje de marcado de hipertexto que trabaja con etiquetas y se ejecuta en el lado del cliente

En el lado del cliente tenemos a

- HTML
- CSS
- JS

Estos son interpretados en conjunto por el navegador que finalmente muestra el resultado en pantalla

HTML fue creado por el científico *Tim Berners-Lee* en 1993 y actualmente, está en su versión 5

Por lo general la extensión de un archivo HTML es *.html* y *.htm* y su tipo MIME es *text/html*, aunque la extensión puede variar si el servidor especifica que un archivo se tiene que interpretar con el tipo MIME específico

---

**HTML NO es considerado un lenguaje de programación** porque

- Es solo marcado, el cual será texto
- No tiene funcionalidades que cambien o modifiquen algo en el servidor o en el documento actual

---

Cada archivo HTML válido deberá tener la declaración de documento

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

- No es case sensitive, es decir que no distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas
- No es necesario, pero es una buena práctica

Es usado para declarar el tipo de documento y la versión de HTML empleada en el documento